# solid angle vector field

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I learned that solid angle vector field is A(r) = r/ |r|^3, and it measures the solid angle of a surface S by integrating this vector field on surface S. But nobody can explain this result. Can you tell me a

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Yes, the answer is

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\int_{S}{\vec{r} \over r^{3}}\cdot\dd\vec{S}
&=
-\int_{S}\nabla\pars{1 \over r}\cdot\dd\vec{S}
=
-\int_{V}\nabla\cdot\nabla\bracks{\pars{1 \over r}}\,\dd V
=
-\int_{V}\nabla^{2}\pars{1 \over r}\dd V
\\[3mm]&=
-\int_{V}\bracks{-4\pi\delta\pars{\vec{r}}}\,\dd V
\end{align}
$$\color{#0000ff}{\large%
\int_{S}{\vec{r} \over r^{3}}\cdot\dd\vec{S}
=
4\pi}
$$

Comment: Isn't this strange? Surface integral of Solid angle vector field on any surface S equals 4 \pi??